# Poker Hand Evaluator

Tags: java

I have a method the determines a flush, just want some opinions.  It looks through an poker hand array, compares the suits, and counts every time a card is matched, and if it is 4, then it returns true.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
public boolean isFlush(PlayingCard[] hand)
    {
        int suitCounter = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1 ; j < hand.length ; j++ )
            {
                if(hand[i].getSuit() == hand[j].getSuit())
                    suitCounter++;
            }
        }

        return (suitCounter == 4);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need that outer `for` loop, which only runs once, with `i == 0`? Also, do your poker hands have 5 cards, or just 4?

Comment: This belongs on codereview. Stackoverflow is for fixing known problems.

Comment: Ask your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean isFlush(PlayingCard[] hand) {
  Suit s = hand[0].getSuit();

  for(PlayingCard c : hand)
    if(c.getSuit() != s)
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

You don't need to count anything, just return `false` if something doesn't match.